# Using wxMaxima to obtain a transfer function from T-twin filter & op amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, filter, transfer-function

I'm trying to get the transfer function from this circuit using wxMaxima
[image: T-twin filter with Op Amp]

So first using the ideal op amp model I know Vx = Vy and I can know Vy from that voltage divider from Vo
[image: Input equations]

Now I solve this system
[image: Algebraic equation system]

From here I'm not pretty sure what should I do next.

I've tried some solutions without success. Like this
 [image: Fail]

Anyone can give me a hint about what to do next? I'm not pretty familiar with Maxima nor op amps but I guess I have the right idea about this.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion and your time reading this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to add one more equation \$ \frac{\text{Vx}-\text{V1}}{R}+\mathcal{C} s (\text{Vx}-\text{V2}) == 0\$ and solve for \$V0\$ as well. Also your first equation needs to have the term \$ 2 \mathcal{C}\$ instead of \$ \mathcal{C}\$.

Computations using Mathematica.

```
sols = Solve[{
(V1 - Vi)/R + (V1 - Vx)/R + (V1 - V0) s 2 \[ScriptCapitalC] == 0, 
(V2 - Vi) s \[ScriptCapitalC] + (V2 - Vx) s \[ScriptCapitalC] + V2/(R/2) == 0, 
Vx == (RA V0)/(RA + RB), 
(Vx - V1)/R + (Vx - V2) s \[ScriptCapitalC] == 0}
, 
{V1, V2, Vx, V0}
];

tfm = TransferFunctionModel[V0/Vi /. sols[[1]] // Simplify, s]
```

[image]

Special cases:

1. \$RA = 0 \$, and any value of \$RB\$

   tfm /. RA -> 0

[image]

2. \$RB = 0 \$, and any value of \$RA\$

   tfm /. RB -> 0

[image]

3. \$R = 0 \$, and any value of \$\mathcal{C}\$

   tfm /. R -> 0

   [image]
4. \$\mathcal{C} = 0 \$, and any value of \$R\$

   tfm /. \[ScriptCapitalC] -> 0

   [image]

These are notch filters when \$\text{RA}<\text{RB}\$.

```
values = {0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000};
Table[tfm /. {RA -> 1, RB -> 10, R -> f/\[ScriptCapitalC]}, {f, values}];
BodePlot[%, PlotLayout -> "Magnitude", PlotLegends -> values]
```

[image]

They are still notch when \$\text{RA}>\text{RB}\$.

```
Table[tfm /. {RA -> 10, RB -> 1, R -> f/\[ScriptCapitalC]}, {f, values}];
BodePlot[%, PlotLayout -> "Magnitude", PlotLegends -> values, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

If \$\text{RA}=\text{RB}\$, it turns out to be "all-pass" filters.

```
Table[tfm /. {RA -> 1, RB -> 1, R -> f/\[ScriptCapitalC]}, {f, values}];
BodePlot[%, PlotLayout -> "Magnitude", PlotLegends -> values, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes - the four cases 1...4 are easy to derive. However, I still think that for RB=0 the circuit must have a magnitude of zero for one single frequency (real notch).

Comment: Could you explain the reasoning behind that. With \$RB=0\$ the system appears as a band-pass filter.

Comment: Analyzing the two extreme cases f=0 anf f infinite we see that in both cases the total gain is maximum with (1+RB/RA). Hence, it cannot appear as a bandpass. It is one of the classical notch filter realizations.

Comment: Sure, it's an all-pass system with constant gain \$\frac{\text{RB}}{\text{RA}}+1\$ for \$R C =0\$ and \$R C \to \infty\$. So it should be a notch filter in between? How do you arrive at that conclusion? And the maximum possible gain is \$\frac{\text{RB}}{\text{RA}}+1\$ for \$\textbf{all}\$ frequencies and \$\textbf{all}\$ parameter values? Again, how do you reach that conclusion?

Comment: Yes - the double-T network is a "tricky" circuit because it can assume a different behaviour - if used as a feedback element for amplifiers with different gain values. For gain values lower than "2" it shows a notch characteristic (and that`s what I had in mind because this is the classical application of this circuit with unity gain). However - you are right, for a gain of "2" it is an allpass. On the other hand - I am not sure if we should call it "allpass" because it has constant gain AND constant phase (all 3 poles and zeros are identical).

Comment: Probably it is an extreme case, so I will put allpass in quotes - unless there is another name. Assuming you are convinced of the validity of the answer I arrived at, I think you should investigate why your answer does not agree with mine and fix or remove it, and in the very least update it so it does not cast doubts on my answer.

Comment: Why should I remove my answer? I am sure that it is correct! Please note that my transfer function is of third order in contrast to yours (2nd order). A comparison is possible only after dividing N(s) and D(s) by the common pole/zero pair. Did you check if your function exhibits a notch behaviour (for unity gain)? I did!.

Comment: It is a simple task to show that your function (unity gain for for RB=0) has a peak of 6dB at the pole/zero frequency and approaches "1" for dc and very large frequencies. But it is known that the circuit exhibits a notch behaviour for unity gain.

Comment: Sorry, but your conclusions are not correct. For RB<RA we have a notch filter (including RB=0) and for RB>RA the circuit is not a bandpass (as you claim) but it is an unstable circuit (pole at the RHP).

Comment: How can my conclusions be wrong unless Kirchoff's laws and the assumption of Vx==Vy is wrong? And what unstable pole are you referring to, because there ain't any, and there can't be any according to Descartes' rule of signs.

Comment: I started with 4 basic and concrete equations and came up with the answer that can be duplicated on any computer algebra system or verified by hand. You are bringing up are some preconceived notions based on your personal experience. Yesterday it was something about the system being "tricky", today you say something about unstable poles, etc, etc, and we can keep going around in merry circles. If you cannot show me where the 4 basic equations (Kirchoff's laws and Vx==Vy assumptions) are wrong, the conclusions are inescapable.

Comment: Suba T., I must admit that I have no motivation and no time to check or correct your equations. That is up to you. But believe me: Your result is wronng! Perhaps you are not involved in filter circuits - but I can tell you that the shown active Twin-T filter is not a new or unknown circuit. It is one of the well-known topologies for realizing a bandstop filter. And for this reason the 2nd- order numerator must show the basic property for a notch characteristic: No s-term !

Comment: You sure had all the time and motivation to throw your opinions and answer around, but you cannot check 4 equations (3 of which were already in the question)? This is not religion to "believe" someone, so unless you have some tangible math to back your claims it doesn't matter a bit.

Comment: I did not "throw my opinions" around - I have written down known FACTS - nothing more. Consult a filter book! Please note that circuit analysis does not rely on opinions!

Comment: Suba T., question to you: Do you agree that the numerator of notch transfer function must NOT contain an s-term? Does your function contain such a term?

Comment: Suba T., did you find your error? If not - here it comes: The 4th equation introduced by you is wrong. You must not use the node voltages which belongs to the input source (it is not a dependent node voltage). Instead, you must use the node voltage Vx for the 4th equation. Thus, all your formulas are wrong. Sorry to say.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time! This is the first tangible comment I had from you. However, how can the first 3 equations also be wrong? So sorry, all my equations are not wrong. It changed the sign of one term in the denominator, and that makes a world of difference to the subsequent analysis, which I have now updated.

Comment: Emphasize was on YOUR equations. The other three equ. were given already. And - thank you for classifying my finding as "first tangible comment from me".

Comment: Suba T., I am sorry - but one of your conclusions is still wrong. You must not blindly trust all simulation results. An ac simulation in the frequency domain cannot reveal instable feedback arrangements! For RA<RB the s-term in the denominator is NEGATIVE!. This indicates instability as I have mentioned in my contribution. It is NOT a notch as you claim. This follows from feedback basics!!!

Comment: The frequency response shows the IO characteristics of the filter when it is stable. It can be inherently stable or stable because it is a subsystem in a larger stable system. In both cases the characteristics shown by the frequency response can be seen.

Comment: Suba T., do you what happens if a pole of the transfer function is in the right half of the s-plane? And - as I have mentioned - a simulation in the frequency domain (frequency response) cannot reveal instabilities because it is a small-signal analysis only! Try to perform a TRAN analysis (time domain) - and you will observe the instability (no linear performance as a filter). Try it !!!

Comment: Please reread my earlier comment. It completely slipped by you and all I will be doing if I continue this any further is rephrasing it like I did with (1+RB/RA) in the other comments section. I am surprised about your surprise, but these latter things are subjective... so what can I say. At any rate, I am better off for my interactions with you, and so thank you and so long.

Comment: Perhaps you have learned that simulations not always tell us the truth - sometimes it helps to use your own brain (e.g. for analyzing the pole distribution of a transfer function).

Answer (score 0):

My result looks different (using a symbolic analyzer):

Numerator N(s):

**N(s)=2(RA+RB)+sRC*2(RA+RB)+s²R²C²*2(RA+RB)+s³R³C³*2(RA+RB)**

Denominator D(s):

**D(s)=2RA+sRC(6RA-4RB)+s²R²C²*(6RA-4RB)+2s³R³C³RA**

Please note that for the selected dimensioning due to a pole-zero cancellation the transfer function can be simplified to a second order function. For a gain of unity (RA=0 and RB infinite) the numerator must not contain any s-element.

**UPDATE 1:** After updating his answer, Suba Thomas now arrived at a second-order equation. It seems that his computational machine was able to detect the pole-zero cancellation.

**UPDATE 2:** Here is the second-order transfer function **H(s)=N(s)/D(s)** after pole-zero cancellation:

**N(s)=1+s²R²C²**

**D(s)=1+2sRC[2-(1+RB/RA)]+s²R²C²**.

As can be seen, the notch filter has a transmission zero at wo=1/RC. The pole-Q is dermined by the expression **Qp=1/2[2-(1+RB/RA)]**.

For unity gain (RB=0) the max. pole-Q is Qp=0.5. For a gain of two (RB=RA) we have H(s)=N(s)/D(s)=1. As can beseen, the gain must not be larger than "2", otherwise the s-term in D(s) becomes negative - indicating instability.

**UPDATE 3:** I have updated my above answer after correction of Suba Thomas`s answers.

Comment: We cannot reproduce how you got the first N(s) and D(s) and how you did the pole-zero cancellation. The pole-zero cancellation is flat wrong. If it was correct \$(2(RA+RB)+sRC*2(RA+RB)+s^2R^2C^2*2(RA+RB)+s^3R^3C^3*2(RA+RB))(1+2sRC[2-(1+RB/RA)]+s^2R^2C^2)-(2RA+sRC(6RA-4RB)+s^2R^2C^2*(6RA-4RB)+2s^3R^3C^3RA)(1+s^2R^2C^2) \$ would be zero which it is not!

Comment: Each filter book will confirm the above result (example: Claude Lindquist, Active Network Design).

Comment: Suba T., may I recommend something to you: Use a circuit simulation program and verify that the circuit as shown (for an opamp gain <2) realizes a bandstop filter (notch). From this, you can derive that there must not be any s-term in the numerator of the transfer function. That is basic! You also can show that for gain values >2 the circuit is unstable. Simple proof.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that your pole-zero cancellation is wrong.

Comment: What means wrong? It is not "my" cancellation. It is a fact that the 3rd-oder Twin-T network (even without any amplifier) for the special dimensioning (2C and R/2) is reducend to a 2nd-order function by pole-zero cancellation. Can be found in any textbook dealing with such 4-pole networks. Can also be proofed by simulation (calculation by hand is rather involved).

Comment: I already showed you the general expressions I entered into an algebra system and easily saw your calculations were wrong. To make it more tangible assume that R, C, RA, and RB all have value 1. This results in \$N(s)=4 s^3+4 s^2+4 s+4\$ and \$D(s)=2 s^3+2 s^2+2 s+2\$. It simplifies to 2. If you substitute them into the expressions you have after cancellation, both N(s) and D(s) turn out to be \$s^2+1\$ and that simplifies to 1. You want to tell me that 2==1 is correct!

Comment: I found the issue with your pole-zero cancellation results. The numerator needs to be multiplied by (1+RB/RA). Then your results are fine, and more importantly they will agree with the result I now have.

Comment: No - that is not correct. Analysis of the pole-zero distribution shows that there is a real pole and a real zero with the same value: s,p=s,z=-1/RC. Hence, to get the second-order equation we must divide numerator and denominator of the 3rd-order function by (1+1/RC). This is the method of pole-zero cancellation.

Comment: You still want to insist that 1==2 is correct. That itself is wrong. Just plug in one for R, C, RA, and RB all see what you get. Another way to see that your are wrong. What is the static gain (DC gain) of the filter in the two cases (before and after pole-zero cancellation). Can the DC gain change because of pole-zero cancellations?

Comment: It is common to use the shown circuit for unity gain only. That is the reason I forgot the gain factor (1*RA/RB) in the numerator of the second-order function. That is all!. (PS: I am a bit surprised about the tone of your replies, try to keep calm).

Answer (score 0):

I only added a new node to the equation system. And removed another node.

We know

```
Vx = Vy = Vo * Ra/(Ra+Rb)
K = Ra / (Ra+Rb)
```

So this was my solution

[image: Final solution]

And thanks for the answers about RA and RB. At lab I saw when K > 1/3 the circuit gets crazy.